On session expire , prompt to user for password, to continue his work
On session expire , we get 401 error in app.axios file and we handle it to prompt a dialog to ask for password and we hit the login API again to get the fresh token and then user can conitnue his work.
Issue is that suppose API-1 gets hit then 401 comes and prompt gets openend we eneter the password and get new token but in the mean while other API's lets say 2,3 are getting hit and data is getting lossed. I am attaching the cancel token as well to the failed API's and retrying it to get new data, but somehow on page reload or navigating to ne page apis fail and i get some missed data there.
import axios from "axios";

import store from "../redux/store/store";
import { updateLoaderState } from "../redux/actions/ui-state.action";

import { APP_PAGES } from "../constants/app-pages";
import { MESSAGES } from "../constants/messages";

import StorageUtil from "./storage.util";
import AppUtil from "./app.util";

import UserService from "../services/user.service";
import AuthService from "../services/auth.service";
import ClientService from "../services/client.service";

// Create a global Axios cancel token source
let cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source();

/**
 * Component is configuring the request and response for axios.
 */
const appAxios = axios.create();

// to maintain the count of api calls, in case of multiple api calls, hide the loader only in case of last call
let activeRequestCount = 0;

// store the failed request to hit again
let requestQueue = [];
// flag to check if prompt is shown or not
let isPasswordPromptDisplayed = false;
// flag to check if we have log out or not 
let isLogout = false;

/**
 * Function to push the failed requests in the queue
 */
function queueRequest(config) {
    requestQueue.push(config);
}

/**
 * Render the failed request again with setting the new token in header
 * @param {string} newToken new token when login again
 */
function retryQueuedRequests(newToken) {
    requestQueue.forEach(config => {
        // assign new token to the failed request
        config.headers['token'] = newToken;
        // assign cancel token as these requests are failed
        config.cancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source().token;
        axios(config);
    });
    // Clear the queue
    requestQueue = [];
}

/**
 * Logout to login page and clear the storage
 */
function logout() {
    isLogout = true;
    // active request count set to 0 as we log out
    activeRequestCount = 0;
    isPasswordPromptDisplayed = true;
    // clear the storage
    StorageUtil.clearStorage();
    UserService.setlastVisitedUrl(window.location.href);
    // navigate to login page 
    AppUtil.navigateTo(APP_PAGES.LOGIN);
    alert(MESSAGES.INVALID_CREDENTIALS);
    window.location.reload();
}

/**
 * Configuring the request : Adding JWT token to the request header.
 */
appAxios.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
    if (!isLogout) {
        // show the loader before any API call
        store.dispatch(updateLoaderState({ showLoader: true }));
        activeRequestCount++;
        const currentUser = UserService.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser) {
            req.headers['token'] = currentUser?.token;
        }
        req.headers['app-code'] = ClientService.getAppCode();
        return req;
    }
}, null, { synchronous: true });

/**
 * Configuring the response received
 */
appAxios.interceptors.response.use(
    (res) => {
        activeRequestCount--;
        // hide the loader after getting the response, only if it is the last api call
        if (activeRequestCount === 0) {
            store.dispatch(updateLoaderState({ showLoader: false }));
        }
        return res.data;
    },
    async (err) => {
        activeRequestCount = 0;
        store.dispatch(updateLoaderState({ showLoader: false }));
        if (err.response) {
            // if you are unauthorized, then we do following
            if (err.response.status === 401) {
                // Queue the failed request for retry
                queueRequest(err.config);

                // Prompt for password if not already displayed
                if (!isPasswordPromptDisplayed) {
                    // set the flag of prompt displayed to true
                    isPasswordPromptDisplayed = true;
                    const password = prompt(MESSAGES.SESSION_EXPIRED);
                    if (password) {
                        const currentUser = UserService.getCurrentUser();
                        try {
                            // Cancel all ongoing requests
                            cancelTokenSource.cancel('Token expired');
                            const user = await AuthService.login(currentUser?.email, password);
                            if (user?.token) {
                                // Obtain a new token
                                // Reset the cancel token source
                                cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
                                // Retry queued requests with the new token
                                retryQueuedRequests(user.token);
                                isPasswordPromptDisplayed = false;
                                return Promise.resolve();
                            }
                        } catch (error) {
                            logout();
                        }
                    } else {
                        logout();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Return a rejected promise to prevent the rejection from propagating to the component's catch block
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
);

export default appAxios;

